# How can I get the total "INTERNET" usage (in MB) using Microsoft Netmonitor or any other tool

Tags: windows, network-monitoring

I tried with Microsoft Netmonitor, but I don't know which `column` has to be added to get the `Total usage (in MB)`.

I also want to know about what filter have to be applied to get only the `INTERNET` usages.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the total bandwidth your machine has to access the internet, http://www.speedtest.net/ from a machine that has flash.

**Updated for more info**

There are performance counters you can use: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749154.aspx but basically add a counter for bytes received, sent, or total per second, then you could scale it (.001 for KB for example, or .000001 for MB/sec), these counters can either show stats for a specific network interface, or for all interfaces.

Comment: This is a server, and I want all the network traffic from client machines, not the internet speed

Comment: please see the edited Question

Comment: @Sreekumar this server is a router that connects your clients to the internet? If not, does it stand between your clients and the internet in any way?

Comment: this is a server router/proxy

Answer (score 1):

A useful Windows utility that I have been using to track my Internet usage on my home machines is found at http://www.hageltech.com/dumeter/about and at last look offered a service to track use of multiple computers using a website they have.